Uncaught TypeError: item is undefined chart.js
Im trying to make a page using vue and chart.js:
    <script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import VueSlider from 'vue-slider-component';
import 'vue-slider-component/theme/default.css';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

const data1 = {
    2010: [50, 30, 20],
    2011: [45, 35, 20]
    // <...>
};

const minYear = 2010;
const maxYear = 2024;
const canvasRefs = ref([]);
const charts = ref([]);
const isPlaying = ref(false);
const currentYear = ref(minYear);
let animationFrame = null;

function createChart(ctx, initialData) {
  return new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ['Male', 'Female', 'NB'],
      datasets: [{
        data: initialData,
        backgroundColor: ['#36A2EB', '#FF6384', '#FFCE56'],
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      animation: {
        animateRotate: true,
        animateScale: true
      },
      plugins: {
        tooltip: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

function updateCharts() {
  charts.value.forEach((chartData, index) => {
    const chart = chartData.chart;
    const data = chartData.data[currentYear.value];
    chart.data.datasets[0].data = data;
    chart.update();
  });
}

function playSlider() {
  if (isPlaying.value) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
    document.getElementById('playButton').textContent = 'Play';
  } else {
    const duration = 15000;
    const steps = (maxYear - minYear) * 100;
    const intervalTime = duration / steps;

    let currentStep = currentYear.value;
    const animate = () => {
      if (currentStep >= maxYear) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
        isPlaying.value = false;
        document.getElementById('playButton').textContent = 'Play';
      } else {
        currentStep += 0.01;
        currentYear.value = Math.round(currentStep);
        updateCharts();
        animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
    };
    animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    document.getElementById('playButton').textContent = 'Pause';
  }
  isPlaying.value = !isPlaying.value;
}

function addChart(data) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const newChart = createChart(ctx, data[currentYear.value]);
  const chartWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  const canvasContainer = document.createElement('div');

  chartWrapper.classList.add('chart-wrapper');
  canvasContainer.classList.add('canvas-container');

  canvasContainer.appendChild(canvas);
  chartWrapper.appendChild(canvasContainer);
  document.getElementById('chartContainers').appendChild(chartWrapper);

  charts.value.push({ chart: newChart, data: data });
  updateCharts();
}

function handleSliderChange(value) {
  if (value >= minYear && value <= maxYear && value != currentYear.value) {
    currentYear.value = value;
    updateCharts();
  }
}

onMounted(() => {
  addChart(data1);
});

</script>

<template>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="chartContainers" class="chart-container">
      <div v-for="(chartData, index) in chartDataList" :key="index" class="chart-wrapper">
        <div class="canvas-container">
          <canvas :ref="el => canvasRefs[index] = el" :id="'chartCanvas-' + index"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <vue-slider :min="minYear" :max="maxYear" :interval="1" :value="currentYear" @change="handleSliderChange"/>
    <p id="currentYear">Year: {{ currentYear }}</p>
    <button id="playButton" @click="playSlider">{{ isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play' }}</button>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
  // <...>
</style>

It appears that whenever chart.update() is being called, I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: item is undefined
configure core.layouts.js:332
beforeUpdate plugin.subtitle.js:28
callback helpers.core.ts:109
_notify core.plugins.js:60
notify core.plugins.js:42
notifyPlugins core.controller.js:1153
update core.controller.js:508
updateCharts DoughnutChart.vue:66
updateCharts DoughnutChart.vue:62
handleSliderChange DoughnutChart.vue:119
callWithErrorHandling runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:195
callWithAsyncErrorHandling runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:202
emit runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:725
syncValueByPos vue-slider.vue:504
dragMove vue-slider.vue:548

I'm a bit of a loss what is causing this. The chart as well as the slider all work initially, moving the slider just fails to update the chart. I haven't found a similar issue yet. I'm using Vite with Node v20.13.1.

Can you please paste the full error? Also where it occurs?

Vue is meant to manage the DOM for you so most of the time using document interface is bad idea, same with using libraries like chart.js that also try managing the DOM in some way.  Maybe try vue-chartjs which is meant to let chartjs and Vue work better together.

If you see the error "item is undefined" when calling update() on a Chart.js instance in a Vue app, it's likely because Vue's reactivity system is interfering with Chart.js. Vue wraps objects in a proxy, adding extra methods and properties that Chart.js doesn't expect. This can cause errors when Chart.js tries to access or modify the data.
Solution: use Object.seal on the Chart.js object before assigning it to a reactive property.
chart.value = Object.seal(new Chart(...));

This prevents Vue from adding new properties, which helps maintain Chart.js's internal structure.
You could then try:
Object.seal(newChart);
charts.value.push({ chart: newChart, data: data });
updateCharts();

Alternatively, you can directly define a Chart.js instance without assigning it to a reactive property.
let chart = new Chart(...);

You can also refer to this question.
